# ignoreUntrackedFiles with sbt-release plugin

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to ignore my unversioned files for a release. This support ticket says that i just need to add the key `ignoreUntrackedFiles := true` into my `Build.scala` file.

When I do this, I get an error trying to build my project

```
[error] /home/chris/dev/scalacoin/project/Build.scala:19: not found: value ignoreUntrackedFiles
[error]     ignoreUntrackedFiles := true,
```

I've added the plugin to my project, but my `Build.scala` file cannot find that key. How do I tell my Build.scala file about that plugin's key?

Comment: Where do you read about "ignoreUntrackedFiles"? Cannot [see](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release/blob/master/src/main/scala/ReleasePlugin.scala) [this](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) mentioned.

Comment: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release/pull/42

Answer (score 0):

There is a big green 'open' button, indicating that that feature is an open pull request. I.e. it doesn't exist yet in the released plugin.